# Objective-C play sound

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, audio

I know how to play mp3 files and whatnot in Xcode iOS. But how do I play a certain frequency, like if I just wanted to emit a C# note for 25 seconds; how might I do that? (The synth isn't as important to me as just the pitch of the note.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399501/generate-dtmf-tones does this help? (in case i understood you correctly at first i was thinking about creating tones in C#.. ;) )

Comment: In this context C# is a musical note, not a language. He clearly asked he wants this on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the PCM audio waveform that corresponds to the note you want to play and store that into a sample buffer in memory. Then you send that buffer to the audio hardware.

[Here](http://www.hulstkamp.com/2008/09/12/sound-in-flash-10-beta-generating-waveforms-timbre-and-pitch/175) is a tutorial on generating waveforms of several types. The article goes into some details on the many aspects to a note you need to consider, including the frequency, volume, waveform shape, sampling rate, etc. The article comes with Flash source code, I think you should have no problem taking the concepts and adapting them to iOS.

If you also need a library that you can use to play the generated buffers on iOS, then I recommend the open source [Finch](https://github.com/zoul/Finch).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Amazing! Flash is great! Actionscript 2 is what I learned to program on! Great language! Yes I should be able to quite easily, thanks again! That's great! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can synthesize waveforms of your desired frequency and feed them to the callbacks of either the Audio Queue or the RemoteIO Audio Unit API.

Here is a short tutorial on some of the code needed to [create sine wave tones for iOS](http://www.musingpaw.com/2011/04/iphone-programming-how-to-play-tone-at.html) in C.